# How to check file existence with Batch Program

Tags: windows, batch-file, dos

I want to combine 3 strings and get the complete file path.
But when i check for the file existance, it is failing.
Please suggest a way to do this

```
set "path=D:\Build"
set "config=x86"
set "type=Release"
set "fileName=abc.dll"



set "filePath=%path%\%config%\%type%\%fileName%"

if exist filePath (
:copy file code)
```

Answer (score 1):

Path is system/environmental variable, so use it carefully.

The PATH is the system variable that your operating system uses to locate needed executables from the command line or Terminal window.

PFB working example for your query:

```
@echo off
set "fpath=D:\Build"
set "config=x86"
set "type=Release"
set "fileName=abc.dll"

set "filePath=%fpath%\%config%\%type%\%fileName%"

IF EXIST "%filePath%" (
    ECHO YES
) ELSE (
    ECHO NO
)
```

Comment: @ Rajesh, how your answer wil help to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to expand the variable with the file path!

```
if exist %filePath% (
:copy file code)
```

Otherwise you test for a file named "filePath". Also, if the file path may include spaces you should enclose it in quotes:

```
if exist "%filePath%" (
:copy file code)
```

Finally, you should not modify `path` variable as Rajesh suggested (nor `date`, nor `time`, etc), but this is not the cause of your problem.